# VSCode Debug cannot "View Binary Data" for negative variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging

When I was debugging a C++program using vscode, I found that negative variables do not have the option of 'View Binary Data'. Is this a bug in vscode, or does it require some configuration to view binary data for negative variables?

I have tried vscode on both Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 and Google for this problem, but couldn't find the answer.[This is the gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZqdI.gif)